# Nspire cx CAS - Laplace inverse fails

Tags: calculus, integration, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

[image: Nspire CX CAS fails!]

I'm trying to calculate that easy integral but I get undef.
When I replaced $\infty$ with $1000$, I got the right answer.
($e^{-1000}$ is zero roughly).
Although this calculator knows that $e^{-\infty} = 0$ (as you can see).

What's the problem?

(I know that there is many programs that can get Laplace transformation easily... I'm trying to fix this issue.)

EDIT:

[image: Replacing (s) with (5)]

Well, it worked when I replaced $s$ with $5$.
Isn't there any way to make assumptions?
Or storing a number as a variable and getting the answer in terms of it somehow...

EDIT2:
[image: Worked!!]

It worked with a little trick :D
I used the number $e$ or $\pi$ to get the answer in terms of them

Comment: Does the calculator know you're assuming $s > 0$?  It can't read your mind.

Comment: Dear users: instead of flagging this as "low quality", comment and tell the OP how he can improve his post.

Comment: Your trick with magic numbers $e$ and $\pi$ is dangerous: you could get the answer which could have more instances of them, and then simplification and replacing them with $s$ would give you the wrong answer. Instead I'd try using essentially positive $s$, like $m^2$ (if your calculator doesn't assume the variables to be complex) or even just $|s|$.

Comment: Or, if it doesn't assume $s\ne0$, then use something like $|p|+1=s$, so that $s>0$ strictly.

Comment: Nothing of that even worked.. I don't get it, how using magic numbers could lead to a wrong answer?! if it's s^2 then it'll be e^2... can you explain with an example? Thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old question but the answer might help someone :

In fact you just have to define $s$ as $s>0$ with the '|' symbol, like this (screenshot in the link) :
[Usage of the '|' symbol to define assumption for $s$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbolH.jpg)

You can use '|' whenever you have to specify an assumption to the calculator.

Comment: I knew this long time ago but I totally forgot about this question. Thanks, this might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be 100% sure that this is why your calculator is doing this, but here is a possibility:

The integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\,dt$ converges to $\dfrac{1}{s}$ only if $\text{Re}[s]  > 0$.

However, the integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1000}e^{-st}\,dt$ equals $\dfrac{1}{s} - \dfrac{e^{-1000s}}{s}$ for any value of $s$ except $0$.

If the calculator made the assumption that $s \neq 0$ but doesn't know to assume $\text{Re}[s]  > 0$, then it might think the first integral isn't defined, while correctly outputting the value for the 2nd integral.

Comment: I edited the question, it worked when I replaced s with 5 or any number. I'll try to look for how to make assumptions or use symbols instead of numbers. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this program, It's for the TI nspire cx cas it does Laplace & inverse Laplace including the Dirac (impulse) and Heaviside step functions. the instructions are in French. You can always use google to translate the info. http://seg-apps.etsmtl.ca/nspire/enseignement/ETS_specfunc.tns